# scoped thread wrapper for std::thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11, move-semantics, clang++, stdthread

I am trying to make a scoped thread.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class ScopedThread {
 public:
    template< class Function, class... Args>
    explicit ScopedThread( int id, Function&& f, Args&&... args)
        : m_thread( std::ref(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
        , id(std::move(id)) {
    }



    int getId() const { return id; }

    ~ScopedThread() { m_thread.join(); }
 private:
    std::thread m_thread;
    int id;

};

class Worker {
 public:
    Worker(int id): thd(id, &Worker::work, this) { }

    void work() {
       for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        std::cout << "I am working" << std::endl;
    }


 private:
    ScopedThread thd;
};

int main() {
    Worker(1);
    Worker(2);
    Worker(3);
    Worker(4);
}
```

When I run the code, it dumps core.

```
#0  0x00007ffcfbbc6380 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000004026c9 in std::_Mem_fn<void (Worker::*)()>::operator()<, void>(Worker*) const (this=0x7f0b43551de0, __object=0x7ffcfbbc63c0)
    at /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/functional:601
#2  0x00000000004025cd in std::__invoke<void (Worker::*)(), Worker*> (__f=@0x7ffcfbbc6360: (void (Worker::*)(Worker * const)) 0x7ffcfbbc6380, this adjustment 4198629,
    __args=<unknown type in /home/asit/cpp/scope_thd, CU 0x0, DIE 0x2abf>) at /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/functional:247
#3  0x0000000000402532 in std::reference_wrapper<void (Worker::*)()>::operator()<Worker*>(Worker*&&) const (this=0x1b27048,
    __args=<unknown type in /home/asit/cpp/scope_thd, CU 0x0, DIE 0x57fb>) at /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/functional:467
#4  0x00000000004024d2 in std::_Bind_simple<std::reference_wrapper<void (Worker::*)()> (Worker*)>::_M_invoke<0ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul>) (this=0x1b27040)
    at /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/functional:1731
#5  0x0000000000402485 in std::_Bind_simple<std::reference_wrapper<void (Worker::*)()> (Worker*)>::operator()() (this=0x1b27040)
    at /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/functional:1720
#6  0x0000000000402119 in std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::reference_wrapper<void (Worker::*)()> (Worker*)> >::_M_run() (this=0x1b27028)
    at /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/thread:115
#7  0x00007f0b44103a60 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x00007f0b43920184 in start_thread (arg=0x7f0b43552700) at pthread_create.c:312
#9  0x00007f0b4364d37d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111
```

Can someone tell me how do I forward member functions and arguments to the underlying std::thread class ? I have observed that, the segmentation fault comes only in clang++, not in gcc.

My objective is to make the wrapper class completely replaceable with std::thread class. Wrapper class takes a new argument for thread id.

Comment: are you building with -pthread?

Comment: yes, I guess without -pthread, the error will be quite verbose. Like,  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted

Comment: well, are you sure you are running exactly as pasted here?  Because that works for me on gcc 4.8.4

Comment: Ya, in my case too, it works in gcc, not in clang

Comment: edited the question

Comment: C++20 is shipped with `std::jthread` for automatic joining. But if you need it right now, why a complex variadic template? Just a `std:: function<void(void)>` argument and pass in a lambda with proper capture list; readable, less confusing with reasonable overhead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several issues with your implementation of `ScopedThread`.

1. There's no need to deal with `Function&& f` separately. Just handle it as part of the `args...` pack.
2. There's no need to move `id`.

   ```
   template< class... Args>
   explicit ScopedThread( int id, Args&&... args)
       : m_thread( std::forward<Args>(args)...)
       , id(id) {
   }
   ```
3. You should make sure that your thread is joinable before calling `.join()`.

   ```
   ~ScopedThread() { if(m_thread.joinable()) m_thread.join(); }
   ```

Applying these changes [prevents the segmentation fault on clang++](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/pswuQ6LT6H9QFPxW).

---

The culprit is `std::ref(f)` - you're creating a temporary `reference_wrapper` and passing it to `std::thread`'s constructor which uses `std::invoke` to call it.

According to `g++` and *UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer*:

> /usr/local/gcc-head/include/c++/7.0.1/bits/invoke.h:73:46:
>
> runtime error: member call on misaligned address 0x7fff939ec8d3 for
>   type 'struct Worker', which requires 8 byte alignment

The problem is that you're creating a **reference to a temporary** using `std::ref(f)`, where the temporary is `&Worker::work`.

[Copying `f` instead of using `std::ref` doesn't cause any segfault or UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer diagnostic.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6994a7d06e69119)

Comment: so the main thing it seems is to use std::forward(f) instead of std::ref.  Can you explain why this was causing the crash?

Comment: @MK. Just added an explanation. I think that the issue was that `std::ref(f)` was creating a `reference_wrapper` to a temporary, and then passing it to `std::thread::thread` for invocation.

Comment: `if(m_thread.joinable()) m_thread.join();`: when the thread can be already destroyed in this case? aren't members destroyed on leaving destructor?

Comment: @AndyT: I assumed that *move operations* were eventually going to be implemented for `ScopedThread`. In that case, moving from an `std::thread` instance may leave it non-joinable.

Comment: @AndyT no, the order of destruction is ~destructor, then the members.  So m_thread will be alive when ~ is executed.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: yeah, makes sense. do you think move semantics is appropriate in this case? wouldn't it be moving *scoped* thread out of scope?

Comment: @AndyT: I would see it as an "ownership transfer" - think of `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

My 5 cents for anyone who research the topic.

I did cleanup the code and implemented deleted constructors:

```
class ScopedThread{
public:
    template<class ...Args>
    explicit ScopedThread(Args &&...args) : thread_(std::forward<Args>(args)...){}

    ScopedThread(ScopedThread &&other){
        thread_ = std::move(other.thread_);
    }

    ScopedThread &operator=(ScopedThread &&other){
        thread_ = std::move(other.thread_);
        return *this;
    }

    std::thread &operator*(){
        return thread_;
    }

    std::thread const &operator*() const{
        return thread_;
    }

    std::thread *operator->(){
        return & operator*();
    }

    std::thread const *operator->() const{
        return & operator*();
    }

    auto get_id() const{
        return thread_.get_id();
    }

    auto join(){
        if (thread_.joinable())
            thread_.join();
    }

    ~ScopedThread(){
        join();
    }

private:
    std::thread thread_;
};
```